# How to post Handsontable data into WordPress REST API?

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, api, handsontable

I'm trying to post the data from Handsontable into WordPress using WP REST API. This is what I tried :

```
 $('#publish').on('click',function(e){
            var data = JSON.stringify(hot.getDataAtRow(0));
            $.ajax({
                url: 'domain.com/staging/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/',
                method: 'POST',
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: data,
                beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', wpApiSettings.nonce );
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    console.log( data );
                },
                error: function ( error ) {
                    console.log( error );
                }
            });
        });
```

I get this response :

> {"code":"empty_content","message":"Content, title, and excerpt are
>   empty.","data":{"status":400}}

However, the output of **JSON.stringify(hot.getDataAtRow(0))** is looks like this :

```
["John Doe","Sample text","publish"]
```

I tried manual way by set the data like this, it works :

```
data: {
  "title": "John Doe",
  "content": "Sample text",
  "status": "publish"
}
```

So my question is :
How to get the data from Handsontable on that format? I need to set which field is the title, content, status, excerpt, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The output of your `JSON.stringify(hot.getDataAtRow(0))` gets you an array of strings, whereas API expects an object with 3 fields.

Try:

```
var data = {
  "title": hot.getDataAtCell(0, 0),
  "content": hot.getDataAtCell(0, 1),
  "status": hot.getDataAtCell(0, 2),
};
```

And then in your AJAX call:

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```